# When I POST to HTTP instead of HTTPS it calls the get route instead

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

We have two routes under a base route of /MyObjects defined as:

```
@GetMapping
public List<MyObject> getAll() {}

@PostMapping
public MyObject create(MyObject myObjectJson) {}
```

When we call the following we get the results:

GET - https://host/MyObjects : returns a list of all MyObjects

POST - https://host/MyObjects (with json data) : creates a new MyObject

POST - http://host/MyObjects : **returns a list of all MyObjects**

I have no idea why that last one happens and I'd prefer to prevent all http calls from even being allowed. Can anyone explain why it's happening and/or how to prevent it?

I'm not sure if it's our route definition or if it falls under a security thing.

Comment: Something on the host redirecting to the https side and causing it to perform a GET instead?

Comment: Apparently? I have full control over everything locally. I can't tell why it would redirect like that just because I went from HTTPS to HTTP

Comment: webserver config can do it, either a redirect set up and listening on port 80 or perhaps HSTS and your browser knows it should go secure instead.